# On two related models, which one should contain the definition of the relationship?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, model, relational-database

*First of all, yes: I've read Django's [foreign key and many-to-many documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), but I'm still not 100% clear on how to implement relationships on a practical level, especially regarding the hierarchy of the relationships.*

1. One-to-one

I am aware of how to form one-to-one relationships. However, on a more conceptual level, which model should contain that reference to the other one? Let's say I have a `Citizen`, and a `Passport`. Now, it's obvious that one `Citizen` can only have a single `Passport` and viceversa, but, **ideally**, should the `Citizen` contain a field referencing to his `Passport`, or should the `Passport` model contain a reference to the `Citizen` it belongs to?

2. Many-to-many

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have a `Person` model and a `Trip` model (`Trip` as in going out on a trip somewhere). Many `Persons` can participate in a single `Trip`. Or in other words: a `Person` can participate in many `Trips` and in any single `Trip`, a lot of `Persons` can participate. This looks like a many-to-many relationship, but, again, **ideally**, which model should contain the definition for the relationship, the `Person` with a `trips` field or the Trip with a `participants` field? And why? Does it even make any practical difference?

Thank you.

Comment: Logically passports are issued to citizens so passport should have reference to citizen. On the other hand Citizens have passports so citizen should have reference to passport. Now my point is that its a logical problem. If your webapp is for seeing citizen info then use latter otherwise use former

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your business logic. As a rule of thumb I'd suggest to think about the admin app. How would you like to add new objects?

When adding new objects, how would you like to add related objects?

Let's say you have these models:

```
Citizen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

Passport(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField()
    citizen = models.OneToOneField('Citizen', related_name='passport')
```

When adding new passport object, you have the possibility to add new citizen, if it doesn't yet exist. Since this doesn't look very logical to me, I'd change the relation as:

```
Citizen(models.Model):
    # other fields
    passport = models.OneToOneField('Passport', related_name='citizen')
```

Now we can add a new citizen object in the admin and add the related passport object within the same page.

If you use the admin app, this should lead you to more ergonomical design.

EDIT: expand with many-to-many example

Better example for a m2m relation would be StackOverflow - there are questions and tags. A question has many tags, and a tag has many questions. Let's say the models look like this:

```
Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', related_name='questions')

Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Why do we put the relation in Question? This should be very logical - when creating a new question you'd like to set the tags for it. When creating a new tag you don't care about any questions associated with it. You can create a tag and later when creating questions, associate them with the tag.
If a tag doesn't exist yet you can add it from the admin, when adding a new question.

I hope this second example is more palpable.

Answer (score 1):

The mental model that you should have is Parent and Child. Every relationship has two models. So think of one as the Parent model or the Primary model and think of the other one as the Child model or the Secondary model.

NOTE: Always put your relationship field in the CHILD model.

Here is how I would solve your problems:

For the first one, I will have a mental model that Citizen is the Parent and Passport is the child.

```
class Citizen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    info = models.TextField()

class Passport(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Citizen)
    unique_no = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

For the second problem, do the same. I would choose Person as the parent model and Trip as the child model.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    info = models.TextField()

class Trip(models.Model):
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    info = models.TextField()
```

If you have `sqlitebrowser`, you can use that to open your database and check what tables were created according to your models. Then, you will have a clearer idea as to how Django sees your models.

Comment: I've noticed, in your second example, that you've used `ForeignKey(Person)` to reflect the relationship; however, would that also account for the fact that a single `Trip` can have many `Persons` participating, like I mentioned in my question? Wouldn't that require a `ManyToMany` relationship, or am I confused about this?

Comment: My apologies. That should be ManyToMany. Yes you are correct. I will edit once I'm home on my PC. Right now I am using the SO app on phone.

Answer (score 1):

The theory behind this is called [*database normalization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) which is a ladder of best practices you should look up if you want to know more about how to structure your data.

The third form tells us that:

> "[Every] non-key [attribute] must provide a fact about the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key."

So in the case of ForeignKey fields it should be on the Child model, because it doesn't tell us anything about the parent, but it does tells us what parent the child belongs to.